# Eggs from mr.developer are not linked in buildout scripts

Tags: django, buildout

I have this config in bulidout. (All other info skipped, the \ means same line, just for readability here.)

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer
auto-checkout = *

[sources]
media_bundler = git git://github.com/culebron/django-media-bundler.git rev=...
M2Crypto.git = git git://github.com/tobiasherp/M2Crypto.git rev=....
```

This eggs are downloaded and checked out, and built (the `.egg` folders are created). Also I see in `develop_eggs`, links to both of them.

M2Crypto then appears in `bin/django`, but media_bundler does not, and all django commands result in this error message:

```
$ bin/django runserver
importing
Error: No module named media_bundler
```

What have I missed in the config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out all I needed was to include these packages in eggs. M2Crypto was some other package requirement, that's why it was included. `media_bundler` is not package name, use `django-media-bundler` instead. Add these packages in eggs in `buildout:eggs` section:

```
eggs =
    django-media-bundler
    M2Crypto
    django == 1.6.1
```

and then see their source folders appear in `bin/django`.